# New laravel install, why will page not load

Tags: laravel-5

I am brand new to laravel applications. I have completed a fresh install of laravel and would now like to see it run live. I have used the artisan serve and got it to run locally, but would like to see it on my remote amazon server. I have adjusted permissions on the storage, bootstrap, cache directories to 777(i know 777 is dangerous), but when i go to the ip address, it always give me a 500 error. I have also adjusted in the apache config, in sites available, to point at the public folder of my project.  What other steps are necessary to serve this from my remote server? Are there other directories where permissions need to be adjusted?

Comment: 500 means server error. If you don't even post the server log or error message then it's very difficult to help.

Comment: This page isn’t working

xx.xxx.xxx.xx is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Go to your Amazon server (using SSH or FTP or whatever you're using) and try to read the logs Laravel wrote. The useful information may be there.

Comment: If I tail -f my apache error.log I get a php parse error for helpers.php in laravel. function event(...$args)
    {
        return app('events')->dispatch(...$args);}